# Patching an exe with NOPs

Tags: qt

I'm new to reverse engineering. I started off here and I was working on the first file "Muadib1.zip". I replaced `E842000000` with `909090909090` in a hex editor, but it seems like it broke the exe. Any ideas why it's not working?

I also tried replacing the sequence with just 5 NOP's instead of 6 but the result was the same.

Comment: an E8 call without prefixes should be 5 bytes on x86

Comment: is it ok if we revert the previous version of this post? It's a pity that we will close with such good answer from @Norwald

Comment: Die.234567767654454443344444433445555555555555455544

Answer (score 8):

The problem is: **you are smashing the stack**.

Lets look at the function you want to patch:

[image]

As you can see, it pushes four parameters to the stack and calls USER32!MessageBoxA. A quick look at its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) shows us, it expects four parameters and utilizes the standard WINAPI calling convention (also known as [__stdcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=vs.110).aspx)). One thing in its description is crucial to this case:

> the callee cleans the stack

(You can also see the function does no cleanup itself, otherwise we could expect something like `add esp, 16`)

That means if we NOP-out the call, we have to NOP-out the function setup as well:

[image]

Kind regards